# Ecape only single backslash and leave double backslashes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have scenario to escape single backslash in string, but it can also contain double backslashes too.

```
"<p>&nbsp; \\$%&amp;;&ntilde;&aacute;&lt; &gt;</p>\r\n"
```

To

```
 "<p>&nbsp; \\$%&amp;;&ntilde;&aacute;&lt; &gt;</p>\\r\\n"
```

How do I do this in ruby. please note I m keeping the existing double '\' intact.

Thanks

Comment: `\r` is *one* character, just like `\n`, `\t` and ``\\``. It's *not* a backslash followed by another character.

Comment: Your input seems suspicious to me because it is not following the convention of the rest of the string.  I would expect if you wanted \\ as an output you would only have \ as an input.  My gut says you don't actually want to do what you are saying you want to do...

Comment: @RickSmith, I agree with you. However, I m getting the input from an editor and somone added \ already which escaped to \\, But the other chars are added by editor. So I have less control on that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like this:

```
"<p>&nbsp; \\$%&amp;;&ntilde;&aacute;&lt; &gt;</p>\r\n".gsub("\r","\\r").gsub("\n","\\n")
```

Comment: Hey Thank you for the response. What if I get '\t', Isn't there any generic solution in ruby??